# How to get a token when a User Login or Signup

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, token

I am failing to store the user token for users that sign into my app.

I have implemented the code below which helped create a User Section and Token Section in my Database in Firestore.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
    _saveDeviceToken();
 }

_saveDeviceToken() async {

String uid = await widget.auth.currentUser();

String fcmToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();

if (fcmToken != null) {
  var tokens = _db
      .collection('users')
      .document(uid)
      .collection('tokens')
      .document(fcmToken);

  await tokens.setData({
    'token': fcmToken,
  });
}}
```

How can I get the token from every user that signs in from the code I have implemented?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What happens when you run the code you shared? And how is that different from what you want to happen?

Comment: I have been able to retrieve the token from my device however I am not seeing the token for other devices/users when they login. I want to see the token for all devices that login.

Comment: It's still not very clear. Are you saying that this code writes the token for your own device to the database, but when you run the same code on the devices of your users it doesn't write their tokens to the database?

Comment: Yes!!! That is exactly what is happening.

Comment: There's not a lot we can say based on the code in that case. You'll want to get access to the logcat output of one of the failing devices, and check for errors. I'd also add copious logging, so that you can see exactly where those devices fail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to do what I think you also want to do:

First, getting Firebase Cloud Messaging token:

```
void getFcmToken() async {
  String token = await FirebaseMessaging().getToken();
  print("Token $token");

  if (token != null) {
    await Firestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .document(userId)
      .collection("tokens")
      .document(token)
      .setData({
        'pushToken': token,
      });
  }}
```

Here is the code for Firebase auth userid:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then(onCurrentUserLoaded);

FutureOr onCurrentUserLoaded(FirebaseUser value) async {
print("user loaded: ${value}");

if (value == null) {
  // no userid found
} else {
  // POSSIBLY THIS IS YOUR ISSUE: 
_myUserId = value.uid;
}
```

}

Comment: On the 1st code for Firebase Cloud Messaging where in my code do I plug in getFcmToken()

Comment: I call it in initState() on my main page.

If you are having problems, you might want to add this to your code as well to check if you have permissions:

**pubspec.yaml** notification_permissions: ^0.4.0
 
`var permissionStatus =
        await NotificationPermissions.getNotificationPermissionStatus();`
    `print("push permissionStatus: $permissionStatus");`

Comment: and please check the last rows of my big code example, where the uid is found is different in my code than yours. This could very well be the problem

Comment: I am getting undefined name 'userId'  from the FCM code

Comment: FCM requires many things to work. It might be something with your app store settings if the code I provided does not work. Make sure your FCM setup is exactly according to specs. And remove everything that's not FCM from your code and post your code again.